# Probability of a series of numbers

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I’m trying to find the probability of getting nine numbers in a row. If $1-9$ are the numbers in question, what is the probability of guessing each of the nine correct. There can be duplicates and the order matters. Such as what is the probability of getting $145347671$?

Comment: What does getting a number “correct” mean?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

The total number of possibilities *(techspeak: permutations with repetition)* is $$\ 9 \times 9 \times 9 \times 9 \times 9 \times 9 \times 9 \times 9 \times 9 = 9^9, $$

as there are

- $9$ possibilities for the 1<sup>st</sup> number
- $9$ possibilities for the 2<sup>nd</sup> number
- $\ \cdots$
- $9$ possibilities for the 9<sup>th</sup> number

Only **one** particular  of these possibilities is correct, so the probability is

$${1 \over {9^9}} \approx 0.0000000026 = 0.00000026\, \%.$$